# RichFaces resources take minutes to load and return 304 response in Chrome

Tags: performance, http, jsf, iis, richfaces

We are creating an application using JSF 2.0 / Richfaces 4.2.2. The page is loading fast in IE9(3-4 secs) but is painfully slow in Chrome.

Looking at the Network the problem seems to be that for most JSF & Richfaces resources, the browser gets a 304 response but it is talking long(I'm talking minutes) to finally get these resources.

My web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <description>
            Set the max time in miliseconds set on the "Expires" header for a resource rendered by the default ResourceHandler.
        </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_MAX_TIME_EXPIRES</param-name>
        <param-value>2592000000</param-value><!-- 30 Days -->
    </context-param>

    <!-- RichFaces -->
    <context-param>
        <description>Defines in seconds how long streamed back to browser resources can be cached.</description>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.DEFAULT_EXPIRE</param-name>
        <param-value>2592000</param-value><!-- 30 Days -->
    </context-param>

 <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <!-- If org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy is set to ALL, this should be false -->
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Sample request/response for one of the resources(Chrome)

```
Request URL:http://localhost/weblogicOMIA1003/APOMIA1003/faces/javax.faces.resource/calendar.js?ln=org.richfaces
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=RTJDSDYGFNnmDSVLySxVMJBJyhhm2GKSLtwPXmLtllqy9xh1MJjY!1711646894
Host:10.42.100.123
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 17 Oct 2012 18:13:54 GMT
Referer:http://10.42.100.123/weblogicOMIA1003/APOMIA1003/faces/analytics/trends/BasicTrends.xhtml?NODEID=545&STATEID=USGVDATIKOO1.e.p.hlzjqo1s462
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
ln:org.richfaces
Response Headersview source
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge
```

Comment: Apart of different timing, are there any differences in request/response when done from IE? What about other browsers (FF, IE8-)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. We areonly supporting IE9 and CHrome. I did compare the HTTP request responses for both IE9 and Chrome for the same resource:
CHROME:
Response Headers:
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
X-Powered-By:JSF/2.0
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge

IE:
Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/javascript
X-Powered-By Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2
X-Powered-By JSF/2.0
X-UA-Compatible IE=edge
Expires Thu, 07 Nov 2013 16:24:28 GMT
Last-Modified Wed, 17 Oct 2012 18:04:34 GMT

I can't fathom why IE would get the Expires header while chrome does not.

Comment: I only can think of that there is some logic reading user agent on server side and doing one or another thing depending on that. Try in Chrome dev tools -> Settings -> Overrides -> User Agent checkbox -> try different values. Despite you are supporting IE9 and Chrome only, try testing other user agents as well, it might give an insight of what is going on. Most interesting is request data, as depending on this server decides to go one way or another, playing with request data you should be able to localize what is causing the difference.